# RoR: Model referencing itself multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, self-referencing-table

I have a Room model. Each room has 6 exits (north, east, south, west, up, down), and I should be able to do things like `Room.first.nr` to get the room to the north of the first one. The model I crafted is the following:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :nr, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :sr, class_name: 'Room'

  has_one :er, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :wr, class_name: 'Room'

  has_one :sr, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :nr, class_name: 'Room'

  has_one :wr, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :er, class_name: 'Room'

  has_one :ur, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :dr, class_name: 'Room'

  has_one :dr, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: :id
  belongs_to :ur, class_name: 'Room'

end
```

However, when doing this in rails c

```
Room.create!(title:'sometitle', description:'somedescription', er: Room.first)
```

I'm getting this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Sr must exist, Wr must exist, Nr must exist, Dr must exist, Ur must exist
```

I've been playing with `inverse_of` too to no avail.

Here is my migration:

```
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.text :description, null: false

      t.integer :nr_id, null: true
      t.integer :er_id, null: true
      t.integer :sr_id, null: true
      t.integer :wr_id, null: true
      t.integer :ur_id, null: true
      t.integer :dr_id, null: true

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :rooms, :nr_id
    add_index :rooms, :er_id
    add_index :rooms, :sr_id
    add_index :rooms, :wr_id
    add_index :rooms, :ur_id
    add_index :rooms, :dr_id

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, took a while but I figured it out.

The model takes this form:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :nr, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: 'sr_id', inverse_of: :sr

  has_one :er, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: 'wr_id', inverse_of: :wr

  has_one :sr, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: 'nr_id', inverse_of: :nr

  has_one :wr, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: 'er_id', inverse_of: :er

  has_one :ur, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: 'dr_id', inverse_of: :dr

  has_one :dr, class_name: 'Room', foreign_key: 'ur_id', inverse_of: :ur

end
```

So I can do

```
a=Room.create(title:'the title', description: 'the description')
a.er = Room.find(1)
a.save
```

and this holds true:

```
Room.find(1).wr == Room.last
```

Thanks anyway @Jay-Ar Polidario

Answer (score 1):

You have conflicting association names (i.e. `has_one :nr` and `belongs_to :nr`). Should be something like the following:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :sr, class_name: 'Room'
  belongs_to :wr, class_name: 'Room'
  belongs_to :nr, class_name: 'Room'
  belongs_to :er, class_name: 'Room'
  belongs_to :dr, class_name: 'Room'
  belongs_to :ur, class_name: 'Room'

end
```

I do not think you would still need the `has_one` relationships. Because you can already get the rooms in all directions with just these `belongs_to`

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm still getting `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Sr must exist, Wr must exist, Nr must exist, Dr must exist, Ur must exist`

Comment: do you have uniqueness validations in your `Room` model? If not, do you have uniqueness validations in your `ApplicationRecord` inherited model? These validation errors you receive is because you have uniqueness validations on these attributes, somewhere in your code.

Comment: nope, that's what's strange. However, you pointed me in the right direction. See my answer.